# Python - Multithreading not working (Pulse ProgressBar)

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, progress-bar

In my programm (PyQT) I need to run a heavy operation, and I want to display an indicator (in this case a Progress Bar) during the process. The Progress Bar can be set to "Waiting mode" by doing *self.progressBar.setRange(0,0)*.

The Problem: My bar always goes from 0 (not even started) to 100 (Done). Never is set to "Waiting mode". I am using a global variable to see if the process is done, and give the information to both classes or threads.

Here´s the code.

```
# Link to GUI
qtCreatorFile = "interaface.ui"     
Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)

ready = False

class Process(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):

    # Setting-ip UI
    QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
    self.setupUi(self)

    # Setting Progress Bar to 0 and initial message
    self.progressBar.setValue(0)
    self.resultLabel.setText("Not ready")        

    # Button
    self.runButton.clicked.connect(self.onStart)

    # Thread
    self.myLongTask = TaskThread()
    self.myLongTask.taskFinished.connect(self.onFinished)

    def onStart(self):
        global ready
        ready = False

        print "Activate Waiting Bar Mode and message"
        self.progressBar.setRange(0,0)
        self.resultLabel.setText("Wait")        
        print "Deactivate Waiting Bar Mode and message"

        print "INITIALIZE THREAD"
        self.myLongTask.start()

        # Simulate heavy process
        print "DOING TASK..."
        i = 1
        for i in range (9999999):
            u = i*2 
        ready = True
        print "TASK DONE"

    def onFinished(self):
        print "onFinished executed and set Progress Bar to 1"
        self.progressBar.setRange(0,1)
        self.progressBar.setValue(1)
        self.resultLabel.setText("Done")        

class TaskThread(QtCore.QThread):
    taskFinished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def run(self):
        global ready
        temp = True
        while temp == True:
            if ready == False:
                print "(THREAD)Process not finished yet"
            else:
                print "(THREAD)Process done"
                self.taskFinished.emit()
                temp = False  

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = BagTool()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

PS. I use an .ui for the Interface. I have just a QPushButton and QProgressBar

The process should be:
1- Initially bar at 0
2- Push button. Start process and bar starts moving
3- When process is over, the bar is complete.

If you run the code (with an interface having these two QWidgets) you will see that the process takes maybe one second, BUT during this second, the Progress BAR always stays at 0 (it should move from one side to the other in this waiting mode). When it finishes, the bar shows 1 and the "Done" message.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I see something very strange in your code, for example, the heavy task is running out of the thread. Do not you think it's illogical?

Comment: It´s already solved! You were right. With the task inside the thread it works fine :) Thanks!